# Trigger github workflow whenever there is a commit made to any files or folder that are inside a top level folder that contains a tsconfig.json

Tags: directory, github-actions, workflow, subdirectory

[Spicetify-Extensions](https://github.com/Tetrax-10/Spicetify-Extensions) is my Repo where there are 9 top level directories eg [Sort-by-Play-count, Play-on-YouTube, Play-Enhanced-Songs, etc...] here only "Play-on-YouTube" directorie has "tsconfig.json" inside it. I want the github workflow to happen only whenever a commit happens to any files or folder inside "Play-on-YouTube" (this is a example). Also it shouldnt be triggered by nested directories that has "tsconfig.json".

Comment: There is a trigger subtype for [`paths`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore), you could inform `'Play-on-YouTube/**'` for the PR / push event to trigger when files from this folder are updated.

Comment: I dont wanna add the folders manually. instead just trigger the workflow for folders that contains a "tsconfig.json"

Comment: In that case, you will probably need 2 workflows: the first one that will identify the folders with the `tsconfig.json` files, and a reusable workflow (that would be called by the first workflow for each path identified, using `matrix` for example, or a local action) with the logic you want to reproduce for those folders.